# All objects are invisble, even in solid mode

Tags: rendering, objects, interface, object-mode

I can't see any objects in blender in solid mode it only shows the origin and a orange outline when I select the object. Rendering it in Eevee the object just gets rendered as alpha 0, in cycles you can see it. In the interface I can only see the object in vertex paint or in sculpt mode. In edit mode it's like I have wireframe on. This happens in all of my blend files, even in the default one so it can't really be any wrong options.

[image: example of my problem]

Comment: AMD graphics card? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203615/how-to-fix-material-and-render-previews#comment342453_203615

Comment: good find! @Gorgious